# Is ROS able to support C# language?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to use c# to build robot interface.
I found c# is very convenient,because both windows and linux can run the same c# program.
c# can use mono to run.
So if c# can also be included in ROS, it will be very great~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10399/is-ros-able-to-support-c#-language?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-06-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

C# is not supported yet; if you must use C#, your only option would be to re-implement the [basic network protocols](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Technical%20Overview) in C#, but that will be a lot of work.

If you are just looking for a way to build a platform-independent robot interface, you could have a look at [rosjava](https://code.google.com/p/rosjava/).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-08-10**:
Is anyone who want to implement c# interface? Because I found that many useful libraries like aforge which has a lot of high level of tech like machine learning,neural network,fuzzy,genetic algorithms...etc.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-06-26**:
It's not really necessary to re-implement it. You could also use a foreign language interface and wrap it around roscpp as the old jni based rosjava did it. Of course, that wouldn't run on windows then :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can basically run ROS with any language supporting networking. So, yes, ROS is able to support C#.
BUT there needs to be an implementation and as far as I know there is no C# one.

If you are only looking for platform independence python is supported very well in ROS. Full ROS usability in Windows is somewhat limited, though, as you will want all ROS features.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-08-10**:
You will need to have a client library: "http://www.ros.org/wiki/Implementing Client Libraries"

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-08-10**:
What should I do when I want to init C# program to a ros node (not by rosjava)?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can attempt to [convert](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=Ikvmc) the rosjava.jar into a CLR lib using [IKVM](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=User%27s_Guide)--haven't tried it but it may work.  It basically convert JVM byte code into CLR IL.  Once you have the DLL you just load it like you normally would in Visual Studio/MonoDevelop.

---

Originally posted by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) with karma: 1607 on 2011-06-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-08-10**:
If I can make the DLL file of rosjava,is there any tutorials or documents of how to implement C# program as a ROS node?

**Comment by [Doug Blank](https://answers.ros.org/users/3381/doug-blank/) on 2013-06-14**:
https://bitbucket.org/ipre/calico/src/fbf0d2b387f94b2687ea42f9fe83728927d43f2d/examples/python/MyROS/rostest.py?at=master is an example using rosjava converted to a DLL and used by IronPython. The import clr, clr.AddReference commands have already been done.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is now a C# api, available see: http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscs

---

Originally posted by [st](https://answers.ros.org/users/2686/st/) with karma: 86 on 2012-06-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4